# Measurement of Lebesgue is finitely additive

Tags: measure-theory

Let $I=\{\langle a,b\rangle  : a\leq b, a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$ a interval family bounded of any type of function.

Let $l: I \rightarrow \bar{\mathbb{R}^+}$ such that $l(\langle a,b\rangle)=b-a$

Prove $l$ is finitely additive.

My attempt.

I need prove that

$l(\emptyset)=0$ and $l(A\cup B)=l(A)+l(B)$

In effect:

$l(A)+l(B)=(b-a)+(d-c)=(b+d)-(a+c)=l(A\cup B)$

i'm stuck for $l(\emptyset)$

is this correct?

note: $\langle a,b\rangle $ is only a interval can be open, closed or neither.

Comment: Don't use `<` and `>` as delimeters; they are *relational symbols*. The spacing is different. Use either `\langle` $\langle$ and `\rangle` $\rangle$.

Comment: Is $\varnothing$ an element of $I$?  If so, use the definition of $l$ to compute $l(\varnothing)$.  If not, then there is no hope to compute $l(\varnothing)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emptyset is the open interval $(a, a)$ for any $a$.

For the addition you also need the assumption $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Comment: okay but i don't see very clear how $l(A)+l(B)=l(A\cup B)$

Comment: Your calculation works for the case $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, then we indeed have $l(A\cup B)=l(A)+l(B)$. While if $A$ and $B$ overlap, it doesn't hold..

Comment: Thanks @Berci. Thanks for your time